# Check whether the user's Email is verified or not with firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app with Ionic 3, firestore is used as the backend for the app.

Whenever the new user creates an account he will get an email to verify the provided email. Up to this point my app is perfect.

How can I check whether the existing user is verified his email or not whenever he tries to make login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a Cloud Firestore security rule custom function, which checks the `isEmailVerified` property in Firebase Authentication.

```
function emailVerified() {
  return request.auth.token.email_verified;
}

match /myCollection/{myDocumentId} {
  allow read: if emailVerified();
}
```

Comment: I missed out the token map.  I just updated my answer.  Try it now.

Comment: Did this fix your issue?

Comment: That's great. Please mark my answer, so it a) shows others the correct solution b) gives me some points ☺️